# Want to run Animated Wallpaper

Tags: 14.10

I am looking for an app that allows me to set up animated wall paper such as dreamscenes on windows.  thank you

Answer (score 0):

There's an app called [Live Wallpaper](https://launchpad.net/livewallpaper).You can choose between the following live wallpapers:

* Circles

* Galaxy

* Nexus

* Noise

* Photoslide

Additional live wallpapers can be added as plugins. Also, make sure to install the package `livewallpaper-config` (settings application).

Comment: [edit] include essential steps...  Etc...  ;-)